# Match preceding sibling preprocessing instruction

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I've the below XML.

```
<mainpara>
 <?xpp /MAIN?>
 <?xpp MAIN;5;0;0;0;123;0;0?>
    <para>
     text
    </para>
    <para>
     Text
    </para>
</mainpara>
```

And I've the below XSLT.

```
<xsl:template match = "mainPara">
  <xsl:for-each select="para">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="para">
    <xsl:if test="fn:contains(preceding-sibling::*[1], processing-instruction('xpp'))">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="preceding-sibling::processing-instruction('xpp')[1]"/>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
```

Here My issue is for both the `para`, the if condition is matched, though I've declared to select all the `preceding sibling`s and select only first one of those and check if it has a `xpp`, and in my current XSLT, for 2nd `para`, the `preceding sibling[1]` is `para`, but still it is matching the `if`.

please let me know where Am I going wrong and how can I fix this.

Thanks

Comment: I don't see any `case-cited.entry` at all in the input sample.

Comment: Hi @MartinHonnen, sorry for the confusion, I've updated my XSLT

Comment: Can you explain in plain text what you want to check? I  am afraid a `contains` check on a sibling element and a child processing instruction (which does not exist anywhere in your sample for the `para` elements) does not allow me to infer what you want to achieve. You could also show us the transformation result for the input sample you have posted, perhaps that gives us a better idea what you want to achieve and allows us to suggest an XSLT way of achieving it.